# C++ how to implement a resizable stack array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

In one of my earlier lab exercises I implemented a simple stack program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int count = 0; //stores the indexed number
string myStack[20]; //stores the data from file
string fileName; 
fstream readFile;
string storeFile;  //stores the data as a string

//function declarations/prototypes
void push(string aString);
string top();
string pop();
bool isEmpty();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  
  fileName = "file.txt";
  readFile.open(fileName); //attempts to read the file

      while(readFile >> storeFile){
          if(readFile.bad()) {
              cerr << "File failed to read " << endl;
              break; //loop terminates
                } else {
                    push(storeFile); //pushes file to stack
                } 
    }

readFile.close();

    while(isEmpty() !=true) {  //while file is not emptpy return the top stack.

       cout << top() << endl;
       pop();
    }
    return 0;
}


void push(string value) {
  
  myStack[count] = value;
  count++;
   
}

string pop() {
    if(count < 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        count--; //decrement count for stack
        return myStack[count]; //return top value
    }
}

string top() {  //returns the current element at the top of the stack
return myStack[count];
}

bool isEmpty() { //checks whether or not the stack is empty
    if(count < 0) {
       return true;
    } 
    else return false;

    }
```

I am now required to revisit this program, however, this time modify it so that If you attempt to push data onto a full stack you should create a new array of twice the current size, copy the data from the old stack to the new stack and then delete the old stack without using STL or classes. We are allowed to use dynamic memory

So if the input, for example, looked something like this with an array size of 2

```
  push 1 
  push 1 
  push 1 
  push 1 
  push 1 
  pop 
  pop 
  push 1
```

Then the output would look like this

```
Stack doubled from 2 to 4.
Stack doubled from 4 to 8.
Stack contains 4 entries.
```

How would I implement this? Thankyou

Push attempt

```
int dataCount = 0;     
const int SIZE = 5;
int capacity = 0;
int myStack[SIZE]; 

void push(int value)
{
   if(SIZE == capacity) {
   cout << "Doubling current size " << endl;
   capacity = capacity * 2;
   int* temp = new int[capacity];
   copy_n(myStack, SIZE, temp);
   std::swap(myStack, temp);
   delete[] temp;

   }
    myStack[dataCount] = value;
    dataCount++;
}
```

Comment: "*without using dynamic memory or STL*" - what you are asking for can't be done without putting the array into dynamic memory. An array in automatic or static memory is fixed in size and can't be resized.  What you describe is exactly what `std::vector` is - a dynamic resizable array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau apologies, we are allowed to use dynamic memory

Comment: In that case, you already know what you need, it is right there in your description ("*create a new array of twice the current size, copy the data from the old stack to the new stack and then delete the old stack*"). So what part do you need help with exactly?  Use `new[]` for the allocation, `delete[]` for the deallocation, and a simply loop for the copy (since you can't use `std::copy()`)

Comment: Create a real stack class, not standalone, wide-open functions.

Comment: Also please no `using namespace std`

Comment: It is better to create a class to represent your stack as suggested by @PaulMcKenzie. If you decide to keep using free functions because you don't want to delve into classes yet, at least do not use global variables outside `main` and pass the necessary variables as arguments (by reference) to your functions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau At the bottom of this quesiton ive added what i think needs to be done using STL(Just so I know I have the idea correct, I will change it later). Is this correct?

Comment: Break complex problems into smaller pieces. Do you know how to detect when an attempt is made to push data onto a full stack?  Do you know how to create a new array? Create one of twice the current size? Do you know how to copy the data from the old stack to the new stack? Do you know to delete the old stack? Which step do you need help with?

Comment: @davidlingg2000 essentially, yes, that is what you need. I've added an answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for requires the stack array to be allocated in dynamic memory, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int count = 0; //stores the indexed number
int capacity = 0; //stores the allocated size
string *myStack = NULL; //stores the data from file

//function declarations/prototypes
void push(const string &aString);
string top();
void pop();
bool isEmpty();
void cleanup();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string storeFile;  //stores the data as a string

    string fileName = "file.txt";
    ifstream readFile(fileName); //attempts to read the file

    while (readFile >> storeFile) {
        push(storeFile); //pushes file to stack
    }

    if (readFile.bad()) {
        cerr << "File failed to read " << endl;
    }

    readFile.close();

    while (!isEmpty()) { //while file is not empty return the top stack.
       cout << top() << endl;
       pop();
    }

    cleanup();

    return 0;
}

void push(const string &value) {
    if (count == capacity) {
        int newCapacity = (capacity == 0) ? 20 : (capacity * 2);
        string *newStack = new string[newCapacity];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            newStack[i] = myStack[i];
        }
        delete[] myStack;
        myStack = newStack;
        capacity = newCapacity;
    }
    myStack[count] = value;
    ++count;  
}

string top() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        return string();
    }
    return myStack[count-1]; //return top value
}

void pop() {
    if (count > 0) {
        --count; //decrement count for stack
        myStack[count] = "";
    }
}

bool isEmpty() {
    return (count < 1);
}

void cleanup() {
    capacity = count = 0;
    delete[] myStack;
    myStack = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class That has
-Array start pointer
-current size
-the current position of the stack pointer

- a method that inflate the array , delete the previous one  and copy the data of the previous
  -have a method that push on the stack and one that pops on top of the stack

You can event handle shrinking the stack when pop is less than length of the stack /2